# Как улучшить SQL запрос

Tags: sql, sql-server

Мне нужно сделать выборку с таблиц со следующим условием:

> сделать запрос, который получает список всех продуктов, и цены на
>   2013-03-01

Я написал вот такой скрипт:

```
select st.[ProductID], st.[ProductName], [Price].Price
from (
  select [Product].[ProductID], [ProductName], MAX(OnDate) as [OnDate]
  from [Product]
  inner join [dbo].[Price] on
    [Product].[ProductID] = [Price].[ProductID]
  where [OnDate] <= '2013-03-01'
  group by [Product].[ProductID], [ProductName]
) st
inner join [dbo].[Price] on
st.[ProductID] = [Price].[ProductID] and [Price].[OnDate] = st.[OnDate]
order by [ProductID]
```

И структура таблиц:

```
create table Product
(
    ProductID int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
    ProductName varchar(255),
    Description varchar(max),
    Color varchar(15)
)
create table Price
(
    ProductID int not null,
    OnDate datetime not null,
    Price int not null
)
```

Все работает отлично, но хотелось бы как то красивее все написать.
Какие есть идеи?

Comment: красивее - чисто субъективное понятие. что именно смущает в текущей реализации?

Comment: Я не хочу использовать два джойна, как это можно изменить, скрипт мне не нравится, вот не лежит как то оно все правильно :) а по другом не знаю как переписать.

Comment: есть привязка к какой-от конкретной бд? mysql, mssql, еще какая-нибудь?

Comment: да, mssql, (точнее azure sql)

Comment: количество джойнов не имеет значения. джойны, подзапросы, CTE - это эквивалентные вещи. а вот в схеме базы у вас есть проблема - таблица Price - heap (без ключа), и ваш запрос в процессе выполнения ее полностью перебирает. дважды.

Comment: @PashaPash, ага и индекс по дате, наверное, тогда

Comment: ок, я понял а если не считать что схема БД не очень хорошая, то есть идее как все сделать более привлекательным? вот такой я перфекционист.

Comment: @TarasKovalenko, если не нравится именно второй join, то можно его убрать, делать один join по _[Price].[ProductID]_ и потом группировать и фильтровать уже результат этого join

Comment: @TarasKovalenko запрос нормален. схема базы - ужасна. в SQL имеет смысл только эффективность выполнения запроса. красота его, написание "SELECT" вместо select - вторичны. эффективность зависит от схемы и от актуальности статистики.

Comment: @PashaPash а как с таблицы Price выбрать в разрезе ProductId цену за последнюю дату?

Comment: @TarasKovalenko сейчас попробую написать, вместе с комментами по схеме

Comment: @PashaPash у вас получилось?

Comment: @TarasKovalenko кстати, поменяйте varchar -> nvarchar, иначе с русскими буквами будут проблемы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема не столько в запросе, сколько в схеме базы.

В таблице Price нет PK. Совсем. Единственный способ, которым SQL Server может выбрать что-то из таблицы без PK - это перечитать ее целиком. На большом объеме это будет тормозить вне зависимости от красоты запроса.
Добавьте ключ - или составной (ProductID + OnDate, или какой-нибудь PriceID identity).

После этого посмотрите план запроса и добавляйте индексы по необходимости. Я бы предсказал

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-OnDate_Prod] ON [dbo].[Price]
(
    [OnDate] ASC,
    [ProductID] ASC
)
```

что (на паре сотен строк) приведет к плану вида

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. хоть вы и упомянули Price дважды, реально данные из нее будут вычитаны один раз - при чтении конкретной цены.

Если очень хочется - можно переписать запрос с одним JOIN:

```
;WITH PricesBeforeDate as 
(
    SELECT * from Price WHERE  [OnDate] <= '2013-03-01'
),
IndexedPrices as 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ProductID] ORDER BY OnDate DESC) AS Row, 
    ProductID, Price
    FROM PricesBeforeDate
),
LastPrices as 
(
    SELECT * FROM IndexedPrices WHERE Row = 1
)
SELECT LastPrices.ProductID, ProductName, Price FROM LastPrices
INNER JOIN Product on LastPrices.ProductID = Product.ProductID
```

этот запрос дает чуть меньше чтений на тех данных, что я у себя навбивал, но всегда стоит сравнить на реальных значениях:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

видно что есть Sort, кушающий CPU. Это сортировка по ProductID и OnDate, вызванная тем, что я использовал PriceID в качестве ключа. Если использовать ключ по ProductID ASC, OnDate DESC, то сортировка исчезнет

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Price ADD CONSTRAINT
PK_Price_1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    ProductID,
    OnDate DESC
)
```

план:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в целом выбирать между разными вариантами запроса и разными индексами стоит на реальных данных. Включаете

```
SET Statistics io on 
SET Statistics time on
```

и смотрите output и план. Все остальное - гадание.