# Последняя запись по дате для 2-х полей

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос

У меня есть следующая таблица, из которой нужно получить записи, отмеченные +:

```
-------------------------------
FID | SID | DATE       | VAL
-------------------------------
1   | 1   | 1997-08-12 | 'qwe'  +
1   | 1   | 1997-07-14 | 'asd'
1   | 1   | 1997-06-15 | 'asd'
1   | 2   | 1997-08-06 | 'qwe'  +
1   | 2   | 1997-07-11 | 'zxv'
```

То есть последние по дате записи для FID и SID. MSSQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте оконную функцию `row_number()`. Задайте окно `partition by FID, SID`, внутри которого строки занумеруются согласно указанной сортировке `order by Date desc`. Потом из этого выберите все строки, имеющие номер 1 внутри своего окна:

```
;with vTableName as (
    select
        rn = row_number()
            over (
                partition by FID, SID
                order by [Date] desc)
        , *
    from TableName
)
select *
from vTableName
where rn = 1;
```

По сравнению с запросами вида

```
select *
from <Таблица>
where not exists(select 1 from <Эта же таблица> where ...)
```

данный подход позволяет снизить число IO операций, т.к. исходная таблица участвует в запросе *один* раз.

Comment: то, что таблица дважды упоминается в теле запроса, еще не означает, что из нее действительно дважды будут прочитаны данные. при определенных индексах может вообще обойтись без чтения из таблицы - я недавно расписывал варианты с картинками http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/473426/177221

Comment: но вообще да, вариант с row_number скорее всего будет быстрее, и точно читабельнее :)

Comment: @PashaPash, согласен. Под _таблица участвует_ я имел ввиду таблица, либо подходящий её индекс. Здесь тоже есть куда оптимизироваться. Если из `*` нужны не все колонки, и добавить покрывающий `index (FID, SID, Date) include (Necessary, Columns)`, то в плане будет только обращение к индексу, и вдобавок не будет сортировки, которая есть главный потребитель CPU в такого рода запросах.

Comment: Я бы не был столь категоричен, по поводу ввода-вывода, потому как в вашем случае приходится использовать order by, и при отсутствии индекса по этому полю таблицу еще сортировать надо и если она большая, то это будет происходить на диске. Надо будет как нибудь поэкспериментировать, думаю результат будет зависеть от очень многих факторов ...

Answer (score 2):

По поводу ROW_NUMBER для поиска максимума.
В общем случае ROW_NUMBER - это сортировка, но нам не нужно сортировать весь набор по дате!!! Нам нужен только максимум по дате. Максимум - линейная от количества строчек в окне операция O(n), а сортировка логарифмическая O(n*ln(n)).
Запрос:

```
;with vTableName as (
    select
        rn = row_number()
            over (
                partition by FID, SID
                order by [Date] desc)
        , *
    from TableName
)
select *
from vTableName
where rn = 1;
```

В общем случае будет выполнятся медленнее, чем запрос:

```
;with vTableName as (
    select
        max_date = MAX([Date])
            over (partition by FID, SID)
        , *
    from TableName
)
select *
from vTableName
where [Date] = max_date;
```

Другое дело если дата входит в кластерный индекс - тогда без разницы.
Но в любом случае - зачем сортировать, если нас интересует только максимум?

Answer (score 1):

```
select A.FID, A.SID, MAX(A.DATE) as [Date]
FROM [Table] A
GROUP BY A.FID, A.SID
```

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за ответ. А если у меня есть ещё одна колонка, из которой мне нужно получить какой-нибудь текст? Я пытался сделать таким способом, но пишет Column val is invalid in the select list because is not contained in the GROUP BY clause (produces is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: MIN(yetanothercolumn) или MAX(yetanothercolumn)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Table A
 where not exists(select 1
                    from Table B
                   where B.FID=A.FID and B.SID=A.SID and B.DATE>A.DATE)
```