# Количество по первой дате SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
store.odyid
 ,g.FID
 ,sds.QUANTITY
 ,min(convert(date,doc1.DOC_DATE)) as min_date
FROM [store.move] AS m
INNER JOIN   [STORE.DOC] AS doc1 ON m.id_doc = doc1.ID_DOC
INNER JOIN  [store.move.spec] AS sm ON m.id_doc = sm.id_doc
INNER JOIN   [STORE.DOC.SPEC] AS sds ON sm.id_doc_spec = sds.ID_DOC_SPEC
INNER JOIN   artikul_full ON sm.id_artikul_new = artikul_full.ID_artikul
INNER JOIN   STORE ON m.id_store_dest = STORE.ID_STORE 
inner join [GOODS] g on g.ID_GOODS = artikul_full.ID_GOODS

WHERE doc1.DOC_DATE between @sd and @ed
and doc1.IS_DONE=1 
and store.STORE_TYPE = 4 
and store.odyid < 950
group by store.odyid
,g.FID
,sds.QUANTITY
order by store.odyid , g.FID
```

он возвращает такой результат

```
----------
odyid   FID QUANTITY    min_date
----------
3   1   4   2010-05-31
3   1   6   2010-04-14
3   50  2   2010-08-18
3   50  3   2010-04-07
3   50  4   2010-11-11
3   50  6   2010-09-29
3   50  9   2010-10-27
```

Как сделать так чтоб он вернул следующий результат

```
----------
odyid   FID QUANTITY    min_date
----------
3   1   6   2010-04-14
3   50  3   2010-04-07
```

То есть сделать так, что бы по минимальной дате выдавало количество

Comment: добавьте субд в метку пожалуйста и скажите, что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: Уберите `sds.QUANTITY` из запроса - получите что хотели

Comment: тогда не будет количества, а мне нужно с количеством

Comment: Результат можно далее пересечь с исходной таблицей и вычленить количество или просуммируйте количество( я не знаю контекста ). Может есть способ покрасивее, но я такого не знаю

Comment: У меня плохо с вложенными запросами. Я конечно мозгом понимаю, что нужно сделать сначала без количество, а потом через вложенный запрос добавить его, но руками сделать не могу =(

Comment: Что-то в стиле `SELECT b.feild1, b.field2, a.field1, b.field3 FROM [STORE.DOC.SPEC] a JOIN ( <ваш запрос без количества> ) b ON ( a.some_field=b.some_field )`. Без тестовой базы лучше написать не смогу( может и сейчас хрень написал ).

Comment: Оберните ваш запрос в еще один, где не будет группировки, укажите min date

Comment: Кстати можно вообще убрать group by, пронумеровать записи по дате и взять первые из них, так гораздо проще, чем подзапросы городить. И это будет правильным ответом, так что предлагаю закрыть вопрос по дублю ...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Последняя запись по дате для 2-х полей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477872/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-2-%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9)

Comment: Я решил, вопрос через временную таблицу и два запроса. То есть я дропаю результат запроса без количества, потом с количеством и джойню их и делаю из них выборку.

Answer (score 0):

Идея использовать window functions

```
with [data] AS (
  SELECT 
store.odyid
 ,g.FID
 ,sds.QUANTITY
 ,min(convert(date,doc1.DOC_DATE)) as min_date
FROM [store.move] AS m
INNER JOIN   [STORE.DOC] AS doc1 ON m.id_doc = doc1.ID_DOC
INNER JOIN  [store.move.spec] AS sm ON m.id_doc = sm.id_doc
INNER JOIN   [STORE.DOC.SPEC] AS sds ON sm.id_doc_spec = sds.ID_DOC_SPEC
INNER JOIN   artikul_full ON sm.id_artikul_new = artikul_full.ID_artikul
INNER JOIN   STORE ON m.id_store_dest = STORE.ID_STORE 
inner join [GOODS] g on g.ID_GOODS = artikul_full.ID_GOODS

WHERE doc1.DOC_DATE between @sd and @ed
and doc1.IS_DONE=1 
and store.STORE_TYPE = 4 
and store.odyid < 950
group by store.odyid
,g.FID
,sds.QUANTITY
),
[data1] AS (
select 
  [data].*, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY odyid , QUANTITY desc) AS rowNumber    
 from [data]
)
select * from [data1] where rowNumber = 1
```