# Вывод строк с минимальным значением цены в группе

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо вывести минимальную цену и название книги по каждой теме. Как в таблицу добавить название книги? По запросам использовать SELECT, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, create view, функцию min();

```
  select themes,min(price) as [Минимальная цена]
  FROM table
  Group by themes
```

Comment: Что нибудь в этом роде https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477877/194569

Comment: Версия sql-server у вас какая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM datatable t1, ( SELECT Themes, MIN(Price) Price
                     FROM datatable t2
                     GROUP BY Themes
                   ) t3
WHERE t1.Price = t3.Price
  AND t1.Themes = t3.Themes
```

Работает во всех версиях. Но для версий от 2005 и старше лучше воспользоваться советом @Mike. С той лишь разницей, что при наличии нескольких записей с равной минимальной ценой для вывода всех таких записей в коде по ссылке нужно использовать не ROW_NUMBER(), а RANK() или DENSE_RANK().

Answer (score 1):

Вариант работающий с 2005 версии:

```
;with myTable as (
    select
        min_price = min(price)
            over (partition by themes)
        , *
    from table
)

select name,themes,price
from myTable
where [price] = min_price;
```

Вариант работающий до 2005 версии:

```
select name,themes,price from table A
 where not exists(select 1
                    from table B
                   where B.themes = A.themes and B.price<A.price)
```